# Sammy.js tutorial; templates throwing errors?

Tags: javascript, html, sammy.js

I'm attempting to follow the Sammy.js tutorial they have on their documentation site, and when I attempt to render my template it throws me:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) sammy.template-latest.min.js:5

in Chrome.  And in Firefox:

> [14:55:55.136] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @ mysitehere/workspace/scripts/vendor/sammy/plugins/sammy.template-latest.min.js:5

My application script is:

```
(function($) {

var app = $.sammy('#main', function() {

    this.use('Template');

    this.around(function(callback) {
      var context = this;
      this.load('data/items.json')
          .then(function(items) {
            context.items = items;
          })
          .then(callback);
    });


    this.get('#/', function(context) {
        context.app.swap('');           
        $.each(this.items, function(i, item) {
            context.render('templates/item.template', {id: i, item: item})
           .appendTo(context.$element());
        });
    });

});

$(function() {
  app.run('#/');
});
```

})(jQuery);

In markup, I've imported:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/sammy/sammy-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/sammy/plugins/sammy.template-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/sammy/plugins/sammy.json-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="scripts/application/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

All of which resolve as 200's.

My template path is verified and copied from their github repo.

I did hear that it's a possible Chrome issue for pulling data not on the http:// protocol but I also tried in FF to no avail either.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it possible for you to create a fiddle? also I'm having trouble seeing why you wrap sammy in jquery, try Sammy( not $.sammy( maybe

Comment: I was just following their tutorial which uses Sammy the same way (https://github.com/quirkey/the_json_store/blob/master/javascripts/json_store.js).  I can try but since the templates are separate files, im not sure if it's recreatable.

Comment: the links broken :) also interesting is how you use context as it was a jquery object (`context.render(...).appendTo(...)`)

Comment: https://github.com/quirkey/the_json_store

Try this one :)

Comment: http://trum.lt/the_json_store-master/#/ I hosted it here - no problems so far :\

Comment: hmm, when I went back a cloned the store example and used the non-minified ones, they worked... So maybe it's an issue with the minified version? or idk :S. THanks though